# Show userid's for each history route

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, analytics, react-ga

I implemented google analytics in my react website with the help of react-ga npm module.
I'm able to generate user report

[image: user report]

and page view report

[image]
App.js

```
history.listen(location => {
     ReactGA.set({ userId: sessionStorage.getItem("networkId") }); 
     ReactGA.set({ page: location.pathname });
     ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname);
});

componentDidMount(){
   ReactGA.initialize(key);
}
```

I want to see who all the users visited "/merchportal/itemavailability" **(user id's, not count)**. How can I achieve this? Is this even possible with the current implementation?

Comment: Let share the code that u implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create segment: users who visited page you need. And apply segment on report USER ID report.